# Firebase Realtime Database cannot get the data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I facing a problem a cannot get the data from the firebase. I did not know why I can add the data to the firebase but cannot get the data from firebase.

```
val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val myRef: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("Event")
myRef.child(name).get().addOnSuccessListener{
                if(it.exists()){
                    status = "checked"
                    existsss = true
                }
                else{
                    status = "not match"
                }
            }
```

I test this code I realize that it will not go inside to this code but why this happen?
This is my firebase rule

```
"rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1633017600000",  // 2021-10-1
    ".write": "now < 1633017600000",  // 2021-10-1
```

Comment: Add a failure listener with `addOnFailureListener` and print the exception to see what the problem is.

Comment: I added addOnFailureListener but it did not print any exception

Comment: make sure `name` is not null in this scope .

Comment: can you share the document tree?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data Please visit this code sample to fetch data. you are doing it wrong all they way.

Comment: "I test this code I realize that it will not go inside to this code" How did you test this? Note that you can't just step into the success listener, as it's called asynchronously. You'll have to set a breakpoint on `if(it.exists()){` and run in a debugger, or use a `print` statement to see if you reach the success listener.

Comment: As Frank van Puffelen already requested, show us how did you test the value of `status`?

Comment: I use log to test the value of status

Answer (score 0):

I change my code to this then I can get the data from firebase:

```
         myRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    
                }
            }
```